# Нужно ли уничтожать переменные после выполнения скрипта? [PHP]

Tags: php

Страницы сайта создаются из отдельных модулей. Используется много переменных, в том числе флаги. Нужно ли их уничтожать в конце скрипта?  
unset($var)

Comment: Встречал только в хакерских скриптах, чтоб хостер их не выловил в логах.

Comment: Интересно, от чего это защитит. С другой стороны, если в определенном месте "уничтожить" переменную, то можно существенно поменять логику скрипта или сильно усложнить его разбор.

Comment: Ну вот тут я не в курсе, но мб где-то список переменных используется. Там просто одноразовый скрипт, делает свое дело, чистит логи и удаляется сам. Штука качественная, потому мне почему-то верится, что автор знал, что делал)

Comment: Я имел ввиду - не занимают ли неунечтоженные переменные лишнюю памать? Нагрузка на сервер и все такое...

Comment: Собственно, единственный ответ - верный. По завершении работы скрипта по памяти проходит сборщик и убивает всех оставшихся в живых)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Они будут все равно уничтожены. И думаю, более эффективно, чем это будет сделано вручную.
А вот закрывать файлы, сетевые соединения (работа с базой - тут отдельная история, часто проще один раз открыть подключение и все пользуются - на лицо экономия ресурсов), ручные выделения памяти - это уже нужно делать обязательно.

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю. Это не совсем ответ к вопросу, но таки нашел, зачем обнулять переменные именно *в целях безопасности*.

licensed_file.php (допустим, зашифрованный etc)

```
<?
$c = 0;
$a = 1;
$user = array('mypasswd' => '12345');
define('DB_LOGIN', 'user1');
define('DB_PASSWD', 'passwd1');
define('LICENSE_CODE', '123123123123123');
?>
```

tester.php

```
<?
include 'licensed_file.php';
echo '<pre>';
print_r(get_defined_constants());
print_r(get_defined_vars());
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
  ...
  [DB_LOGIN] => user1
  [DB_PASSWD] => passwd1
  [LICENSE_CODE] => 123123123123123
)
Array
(
  ...
  [c] => 0
  [a] => 1
  [user] => Array
    (
        [mypasswd] => 12345
    )
)
```

Вывод: во "всяких таких" скриптах константы не пользовать, переменные обнулять. Да, также есть `get_defined_functions`, `get_declared_classes`, `get_class_methods`. Т.е. если вас реально это заботит, скрипт должен быть по уровню близок к школьному паскалю)